# Object Doesn't not support property or Method Error in Javascript

Tags: c#, ocx

I have developed OCX.dll in C# (FW 2.0 with Windowss 7 64 bit OS) with the help of following link 
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24089/Create-ActiveX-in-NET-Step-by-Step?fid=1073139&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=5135502)

and for registering the OCX.dll, I have copied the OCX.dll into windows/Syswow64 folder since my pC is 64 bit and opened the cmd prompt with admin rights and typed following commands there

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framwork64\v2.XXXXX\Regasm /codebase /tlb “C:\windows\SysWOW64\OCXCtrl.dll”
```

and prompt the registered messagebox and i opened the Regedit.exe and search about the classsID and is Its  present there.

I have written sample html code and inside that calling the OCX method using Javascript as like below.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WebForm1</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
    <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" Content="C#">
    <meta name=vs_defaultClientScript content="JavaScript">
    <meta name=vs_targetSchema content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
  </head>
  <body onload="OpenActiveX()">

  <!-- Our activeX object -->
  <OBJECT id="OurActiveX" name=”OurActiveX" classid="clsid:121C3E0E-DC6E-45dc-952B-A6617F0FAA32" VIEWASTEXT codebase="OurActiveX.cab"></OBJECT> 

  <!-- Attaching to an ActiveX event-->
<script language="javascript">
           function OurActiveX::OnClose(redirectionUrl)
       {
        alert(redirectionUrl);   
                    //window.location = redirectionUrl;
           }
</script>


<script language="javascript">
    //Passing parameters to ActiveX object and starting application
function OpenActiveX()
{
    try
    {
        document.OurActiveX.MyParam = "Hi I am here." //Passing parameter to the ActiveX
        alert("1");
        document.OurActiveX.Open(); //Running method from activeX
    }
    catch(Err)
    {
        alert("Error "+Err.description);
    }
}
```

when i run the html code in IE 8.0 then i am getting  following Error

> Object Doesn't not support  property  or Method 'Open'

i dont know Whats wrong with my above code.

Please provide the solutions for the above

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't help you with the Problem but you are aware that MS canceled the ActiveX support with the new Browser Microsoft Edge?

Comment: @Tarsis ,  So Hereafter can't we  work with OCX ?

Comment: Finally  .. Its working fine. made a mistake in OCX registration. Need to do double registration with different framework location.